# How to concatenate Date and DateName together

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to concatenate Date And Date Name Together. How Can I do it.
I need output like

```
2015-10-09 Friday

I got the DateName=  `SELECT DATENAME(dw,'2015-10-09') as MyDateName`
```

Is it possible to make it in a single query?

Comment: Yes, cast to VARCHAR and concatenate with `+`

Comment: @ Bridge, If you dont mind show me a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value you provided is already a string, and DATENAME also returns a string, you can just concatenate together with `+`:

```
SELECT '2015-10-09 ' + DATENAME(WEEKDAY,'2015-10-09') as MyDateName
```

Assuming that in reality this is a parameter or a column of datatype datetime, you'll need to convert it to varchar first. There is no built in style for converting to varchar which contains the Day name, so you'll have to do the work yourself in two parts.

See [MSDN page on cast and convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) for the built in formats.

For the sake of my example, I'll create a datetime variable to use for tests:

> DECLARE @d DATETIME; SET @d = '20151009';

Then to convert it to VARCHAR:

For the date part, ODBC is closest to the format you've asked for with the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)`. So to get the date in that format as a varchar, you can use CONVERT with that style, value, 20.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @d, 20)
```

Note I have converted it to VARCHAR(10) to truncate the timepart of the datetime that you don't want in the output. Then if you concatenate this with a space and the day name you already worked out, you can get your output:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @d, 20) + ' ' + DATENAME(WEEKDAY, '2015-10-09') AS MyDateName
```

(Replace my variable with a column name and add a FROM statement if you're after output from a table)

Comment: @SemilSebastian:- It is DD-MM-YYYY format, so you can use 105 specifier for it while converting your date :)

Comment: Where did you get that information from? The specified date is in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, for which there isn't a built in conversion.

Comment: @ Bridge,. Sorry it was my mistake I solved it. once again Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select CAST('2015-10-09' as varchar(10)) + ' ' +DATENAME(dw,'2015-10-09')
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/5650)**

If your date is already in the varchar format then you dont need to CAST the date and simply try to concatenate them using `+`

```
select '2015-10-09' + ' ' +DATENAME(dw,'2015-10-09')
```

Comment: Why do you cast '2015-10-09' to varchar when it already is a varchar?

Comment: @Bridge:- I was not sure about that. If its already in varchar then yes it can be ignored.

Comment: Well yes, it's in single quotes, so it's a string value. DATENAME also returns varchar already, so neither of the casts are needed here! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + DATENAME(DW, GETDATE()) AS [DATE_WITH_WEEKNAME]
```